# Drawing a 3D tree structure in WebGL

Tags: gwt, opengl-es, webgl

I am working on drawing large directed acyclic graphs in WebGL using the gwt-g3d library as per the technique shown here: http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/papers/h3/

At this point, I have a simple two-level graph rendering:

[image]

Performance is terrible -- it takes about 1.5-2 seconds to render this thing.  I'm not an OpenGL expert, so here is the general approach I am taking.  Maybe somebody can point out some optimizations that will get this rendering quicker.

[image]

I am astonished how long it takes to push the MODELVIEW matrix and buffers to the graphics card.  This is where the lion's share of the time is wasted.  Should I instead be doing MODELVIEW transformations in the vertex shader?

This leads me to believe that manipulating the MODELVIEW matrix and pushing it once for each node shouldn't be a bad practice, but the timings don't lie:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27042/translate-the-modelview-matrix-or-change-vertex-coordinates

Comment: How did you time it? Timings do lie. Some browsers are parallelized so timing is hard. In any case, you're saying it takes 1.5 to 2 seconds per frame?

I don't quite understand what you're doing but simple scene graph with 24 cubes all parented to some center should run at 60hz just fine. Are you (1) compiling shaders once, not in your render loop (2) Not calling any glGet functions in your render loop? (3) uploading your vertex data only once, not in your render loop? Hope those aren't dumb questions but you should be able to draw ~1000 cubes at a reasonable speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group nodes in larger chunks instead of rendering them separately. Do background caching of all geometry with applied transformations that most likely will not be modified and store it in one buffer and render in one call.

Another solution: Store nodes(box + line) in one buffer(You can store more than you need at current time) and their transformations in texture. apply transformations in vertex shader based on node index(texture coordinates) It should be faster drastically faster.

To test support use [this site](http://webgl-bench.appspot.com/). I have `MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS      |            4`

Best solution will be [Geometry Instancing](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter03.html) but it currently isn't  supported in WebGL.

Comment: Isn't there a lib, which can help by rendering the nodes in groups? Afaik d3 is used by canvas as well (not just by SVG), is it good for this purpose?